# How Do I Make Do Loop Work?

Tags: vba

I've spent hours reading through Stack Overflow and other sites, but can't find an answer which works for me. I'm using VBA, and using Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library.

I got the first do loop working, which waits until website is loaded to enter user and password info.

But I need a second do loop, because I am redirected to a second web page where I ALSO have to enter info into text fields.

But - for the life of me - I can't get the second do loop working.

Here's my code (I've indicated the part which doesn't work in **bold**):

```
' Incorporating Microsoft Internet Controls AND Microsoft HTML Object Library
' Webpage loaded constant
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
' Declare Windows API function for setting active window
Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
Alias "SetForegroundWindow" (ByVal Hwnd As Long)As Long
' Declare Internet Explorer object
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Sub Main
SetMicrophone 0
   ' create instance of InternetExplorer
   Set IE = New InternetExplorer
   ' using your newly created instance of Internet Explorer
   With IE
      SetForegroundWindow IE.HWND
      .Visible = True
      .Navigate2 "http://www.NakedCapitalism.com/wp-admin"
     ' Wait until page we are navigating to is loaded
      Do While .Busy
      Loop
      Do
      Loop Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      ' the username and password values will not exist if already logged in
      ' so no need to fill in the values and go straight to Next
      On Error Resume Next
         If Err Then
           'Do Nothing
         Else
          ' When the page is fully loaded enter your username and password
          ' you will need to set these appropriately
  End If
     Dim inputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim iFrames As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim iFrame As MSHTML.HTMLFrameElement
    ' Get top_window frame and navigate to it then
    Set doc = IE.document
    Set iFrames = doc.getElementsByName("top_window")
    If Not iFrames Is Nothing Then
        Set iFrame = iFrames(0)
        IE.navigate url & iFrame.src
              Set inputs = doc.getElementsByName("log")
        If Not inputs Is Nothing Then
            inputs(0).value = "MyUserName"
        End If
    End If
    Set IE = Nothing
   End With
    ' Get top_window frame and navigate to it then
    Set doc = IE.document
    Set iFrames = doc.getElementsByName("top_window")
    If Not iFrames Is Nothing Then
        Set iFrame = iFrames(0)
        IE.navigate url & iFrame.src
        Set inputs = doc.getElementsByName("pwd")
        If Not inputs Is Nothing Then
            inputs(0).value = "MyPassword"
        End If
    End If
```

doc.getElementsByName("wp-submit").Item(0).click()

```
      **' Wait until fully logged in
      Do While .Busy
      Loop**
      ' I take another action here, which I can't execute until the web page
      ' redirects to the new web page

    Set IE = Nothing
   ' Tidy Up
   SetMicrophone 1
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You `Set IE = Nothing` after you input username, but you still need it! For automation don't use `InternetExplorer`object unless you want proced manually, after automation part is done, Use `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` or `WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1`. Username and password are submitted by a html form, see my answer how to use this.

Comment: Additional, [trap errors](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm), the opposite of `On Error Resume Next` which should be used carefully ,)

Answer (score 0):

maybe second time the webpage used ajax or something else but not webpage navigate to do login , so you can not use "Do While .Busy" since no navigation happened there

Comment: I think first of all you should verify what I said is really the case, if so, maybe you can use Fiddler API(I am not very sure if it could be used in VBA since I only used it in C#) to determine if ajax request is complete or just wait a plenty of time before doing your next job

Comment: I guess the question is whether I can add script which keeps a do loop going until an element appears on the new page.  For example, one guy wrote something like this:                                                                        Do Until IE.document.getelementbyid("Name of ID which only appears on the new page").Length>0
DoEvents
Loop

Comment: Or another approach I thought of is to use the do loop script at the top of my code again for the second do loop, but modify it so it doesn't LAUNCH a new IE window, but just waits until the web page redirects to new page?

Comment: maybe Do Until IE.document.getelementbyid could be a walkround way to deal with this , but I am not quite sure if IE.document can reflect the newest IE object when login action is taken. I am not familar with VBA, I did quite the same job using AutoIt, and sometimes its IE object can not reflect the newest situtaion, So I just used waiting a bit long time to solve this issue although it is not very accurately

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it.  The code for the second do loop to wait while the second web page loads is as follow:

```
Do While IE.Document.getElementById("Unique ID Which Only Appears On the Second Web Page") Is Nothing
Loop
```

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score -1):

As you want to input data to a html form and submit it, just do this.

```vb
Public Function getLoginResponse() as String

Dim result As String
Dim myURL As String, postData As String
Dim winHttpReq As Object
Dim strUsername as String, strPassword as String

strUsername = "YourUserName" ' Put your Username here
strPassword = "YourPassWord" ' Put Your Password here

Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

myURL = "http://www.nakedcapitalism.com/wp-login.php"
postData = "log=" & strUsername & "&pwd=" & strPassword ' Set Username and Password to name of input in form

winHttpReq.Open "POST", myURL, False
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
winHttpReq.Send (postData)

result = winHttpReq.responseText

getLoginResponse = result

Set winHttpReq = Nothing

End Function
```

This function returns the html document that you can use like `IE.document`.

If you look at the html form of the site you see

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://www.nakedcapitalism.com/wp-login.php" method="post" style="position: static; left: 0px;">
```

That shows its a post form , so use post method in request.

```
<input name="log" id="user_login" aria-describedby="login_error"
```

That shows name of input for username is `log`, so we use it as first parameter in postData string

```
<input name="pwd" id="user_pass" aria-describedby="login_error" class="input" value="" size="20" type="password">
```

Shows name of password input is pwd, so we use this as second parameter in postData.

Code was stolen [here](http://tkang.blogspot.de/2010/09/sending-http-post-request-with-vba.html)

Comment: BitAccesser,  thank you, but I don't think this addresses my question of do loops. Specifically, there's a SECOND do loop I need before being able to pass text field information to a SECOND web page. I need the second do loop to pause the script until the second web page is fully loaded.

Comment: You have read my comments to your question? Your `IE` object is gone! Combined with `On Error Resume Next` nothing happens, because errors are ignored ;)

Comment: BitAccesser, thank you. I see that you put a lot of time into explaining the script to me.  Unfortunately, as a newbie, I'm still lost.  I tried running your script, but got errors (I'm using Dragon Naturally Speaking, and the error message is "Please correct syntax errors before saving a macro".  Am I supposed to wrap your script in other code?

Comment: No Excel, Word or Access? You should provide this information on question. Code is tested in Excel, but I don't know if there are any vba Limits in Dragon Naturally Speaking. I will test that. You didn't manage to get your code working? Internet Explorer starts? I needed some training in object-orientation so I coded the post submit for IE with catching events in a class. I can use it for a second answer if you want. Did you find the odd `Set IE = Nothing`that destroys your code and get rid of `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: Found [www.knowbrainer.com/forums](http://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=137&highlight_key=y&keyword1=createobject#top) with code that should work with DNS. Use url and form parameters from my answer. I saw your first SO question, where you mention Outlook, if it's not Outlook Express you can use that for vba coding or you can download a MS-Office trial version.

Comment: Thanks, BitAccesser, but the code shown in the KnowBrainer forums only works if the html at the website contains "values".  On some of the pages I'm trying to log in, there are no "values", only "names" and/or "ids".  That's why I had to use such cumbersome code.

Comment: BitAccesser, thanks for trying to explain MSXML2.XMLHTTP and  WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1 to me ... I'll have to roll up my sleeves and dig in when I have more time.